# Abdominal breathing vs proper posture

Tags: breathing, posture

I am having trouble "reconciling" having a proper posture while doing abdominal breathing.

If I understand correctly, proper posture should involve *pulling the abdomen in*, among other things, while [diaphragmatic (belly) breathing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphragmatic_breathing) involves exactly the opposite.

Is it possible to keep the abdomen tucked in, and breathe abdominally at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common issue, you misconceive that pulling belly in is correcting your Lumbar Lordosis, or Anterior Pelvic Tilt (APT).

Your erector spinae (lower back spinal muscles) and hip flexors tend to be tight (and should be stretched), and the glutes and abdominals tend to be weak (and should be strengthened). This typically causes one's butt and gut to stick out. Check here for some guidance on fixing your posture:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/1prg6b/update_to_the_anterior_pelvic_tilt_fixing_thread/

Comment: Thanks. I am only quoting what I found online: e.g. [here](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/adult-health/multimedia/back-pain/sls-20076817?s=3) or [here](http://www.mayfieldclinic.com/PE-POSTURE.htm). I've seen many suggestions that "awareness of your own posture, plus awareness of proper posture leads to conscious correction", which implies that one should consciously adjust the posture to fit the "proper" one. So while I am aware that improper posture is caused by weak muscles, are you saying that a conditioned person actually **doesn't** have to pull the belly in while standing?

Comment: I'm only saying pulling in your belly is the wrong cue. Rotating hips in to position by squeezing glutes slightly should pull it back in. The best person to assess your posture would be a certified doctor.